# USB 3.0 hub status code

Tags: kernel, usb

I'm currently having troubles with some USB 3.0 devices sometimes connecting and sometimes not. The behavior I'm seeing isn't fully reproducible yet, so I had a look into the hub port status provided by `lsusb -v`. But I can't find any helpful documentation on those statuses.

The ones I could figure out myself, are

- `5Gpbs power Rx.Detect` for an empty USB3.0 super-speed capable port providing power and sensing for a device.
- `5Gpbs power U0 enable connect` for the port having a device connected and enabled (providing some defined voltage `U0`?)

The ones giving me (and the device) trouble are:

- `5Gpbs power Polling`
- `5Gpbs power Compliance`
- and only seen once: `C_LINK_STATE 5Gbps power SS.Inactive`

All three statuses lead to the behavior that the integrated USB 3.0 hub then only shows up as USB 2.0 only. Replugging the device doesn't seem to help. Reloading the XHCI_HCD driver in the kernel only seems to work some times.

Most of the times I'm seeing the `Compliance` status, but as I couldn't find any more docs about it, I'm unsure of its meaning.